# Starting Docker for Mac from the command line?

Tags: macos, docker

Is there a way to start Docker for Mac (and / or Docker for Windows) from the command line? I can't find any documentation about it.

My team uses a set of scripts to automate setup of our development environment using docker-machine. Some of us have been testing Docker for Mac and like it, but we don't like having to start a separate app before switching back to the command line.

Comment: Sometime along the way it seemingly was `launchctl start local.dlite` ([reference](https://blog.andyet.com/2016/01/25/easy-docker-on-osx/)). Now I have `com.docker.helper` and `com.docker.docker` running, but cannot locate their plist files.

Comment: What part of Docker are you looking to start? The daemon? The VM hosting the actual docker container should start automatically, IIRC.

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows, but for me the daemon and VM both run automatically at boot or login (not sure which) on Mac.

Comment: @DanielB [Here under Preferences](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#preferences) it shows it runs on user login, the machine shouldn't be started if you SSHed to a booted machine without logging on the console.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking to know the state of the daemon and be able to start and stop it. The scripts we have for various images can detect whether or not they are running, so that's less of a concern.

With regards to the daemon running at startup - sure, that's a safe bet. But it goes down sometimes, so having some equivalent to docker-machine would be good.

Comment: Have you found any solution for starting Docker for Mac from the command line?

Comment: I know this is old, but docker-machine is packaged with Docker for Mac now.

Answer (score 22):

You can open Docker for Mac from the terminal using:

```
open -a Docker
```

I'm using the first production version of Docker for Mac (1.12) that came out last week. You can also have it autostart under Preferences.

Comment: I'm using `open --hide --background -a Docker` to start Docker. The `--hide` makes it not splurge its admittedly cute and cetacean-filled UI all over my screen, and `--background` stops the application getting the focus, leaving me to continue with `docker` commands in my console. If you wanted then to wait until the daemon is actually up, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274294 for ideas.

Comment: Note that `open -a Docker` will return before the daemon is up and running. On my MacBook it takes just under 30 seconds to start up.

Comment: I use this script to retry my first docker command until the daemon has started up successfuly: `open --hide --background -a Docker;
until docker build --tag rkibot .;
do;
    sleep 1;
done;`

Comment: This is not working anymore. The GUI launches regardless.